# Reading (and writing) Opera .adr bookmarks

Tags: opera, bookmarks

Is there any library to parse the `.adr` file format used by Opera bookmarks?
Does it also support writing in that format?

At first, I'd ask for a Python library, but I'm also curious if there are such library for other languages.

Comment: Somewhat relevant: http://www.opera.com/docs/operafiles/#generic documents the underlying binary data format, though not how it is applied to bookmarks.

Comment: @gsnedders Nice link, but it does not document the `.adr` format. That generic binary format is used for other files, but not for `.adr` (which is actually plain-text-ish).

Comment: Ah, woops! I thought it was. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is parser example for Perl language https://github.com/cosimo/Bookmarks-Parser/

Answer (score 0):

I have been tinkering with this recently and wrote [parser in PHP](https://gist.github.com/Rarst/4755736) for it.

I am not sure writing or modifying it is viable, given items contain some kinds of internal IDs whichi probably tie into Opera Link and stuff.

Comment: By experimentation, if you omit the ID and CREATED fields, opera can still import the entries okay, and will create those fields.